# Single isp dual failover links

Tags: cisco, configuration, router, failover, redundancy

I'm having a problem trying to configure my cisco 3945 router to use a dual hand-off wan links.
Lets say the ISP has provided the below ip addresses where they are doing hsrp at their end

```
ISP EDGE 1 IP : 192.168.0.1  
ISP EDGE 2 IP : 192.168.0.2  
ISP VIRTUAL IP : 192.168.0.3  
AVAILABLE IPs : 192.168.0.4 - 192.168.0.6
```

I have one of the fiber link connected to my cisco 3945 **gig 0/1** port and configured it to use **192.168.0.4/29**. And default route to **192.168.0.3**. *This works fine*.
I have the other fiber link connected to **gig 0/2 port**. Not sure how to use this as a fail over interface when fiber link on gig 0/1 goes down.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to set up something like IRB. See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/61111/8499).

Comment: That worked like a charm!! Thank you @RonMaupin.